# Get count from mysql select statement then parse to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I am trying take data from a MySQL table and create a JSON output in the below format.

```php
{
  "count": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "login_name": "testname"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the PHP I am using to generate the JSON

```php
$user = "1"; 

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT 
c.user_update, 
c.id

FROM (SELECT * FROM myupdates ) AS c

ORDER BY c.id DESC ");

$query->bindValue(':user_id', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);

try {

 $query->execute();

 $rows = array();

 while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $rows[] = $data;

}

echo "<pre>".json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

 exit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $error;
     exit();
}
```

Below is the output that I get with the above code:

```php
[
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "login_name": "testname"
      }
    }
  ]
```

What i need is the output count ("count": 1) along with the rest of the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `$rows` array as an element of another array, along with an element containing the count.

This should produce the desired output:

```
//Wrap results in another array
$return_array = array(
    'count' => count($rows),
    'results' => $rows
);
//Print it
echo json_encode($return_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Even if you consider it a trivial answer, please add some contextual comments in order to help other less seasoned developers to figure out what your solution does.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos thanks for pointing it out. I always do, but I'm in the habit of posting the code only first on "trivial" questions - partly to spare others from wasting time writing an answer while I fiddle with my English grammar, partly to give the OP a head start... This time I was interrupted before editing in context... I may need to revise this habit as this is not the first time I receive comments in the (usually) very short period between code only and editing (I suspect code-only is tagged for some sort of review).

Comment: It's not tagged like that, but it's put on the review queue for "Low quality posts". Usually, it's considered length and contents of the post.